# Clean up [embedded] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [embedded](/questions/tagged/embedded) tag on SO has the wiki:

> This tag refers to embedded systems, which are computer systems running on dedicated hardware for a specific purpose.
>
> ---
>
> When asking questions please try to be as specific about your development platform, tool chain, and target platform as possible, unless the question is of broader interest or impact.
>
> This tag neither refers to embedding media into HTML pages (e.g. via the <embed> tag) or embedding programming languages, databases or other things into programs, unless done on an embedded system.
>
> [How do I get started in embedded programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45247/how-do-i-get-started-in-embedded-programming)

It's very clear.

However, some people don't seem to get this.  I've cleaned up a fair number of questions completely unrelated to embedded systems in the past week since I started following this tag, but there are lots of them.  There aren't as many with the tag [on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/embedded), but the ratio of hits to misses is much worse there.

I suggest that we:

1. Delete the tag from unrelated questions. Replace it with the [embed](/questions/tagged/embed) tag.
2. Take some action to prevent/discourage it from being misused in the future, such as merging it into the [embedded-systems](/questions/tagged/embedded-systems) tag.

The wiki is nice, but it's not working.

Comment: The tag was extant on MSO, so I used it.  I'm not sure it should be here at all, it was misused a lot and [I did some cleanup](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146495/kevin-vermeer?tab=activity#page_1-filter_revisions): http://i.stack.imgur.com/0FFjs.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd probably be simplest to just create a tag synonym of `embedded-systems` of `embedded`, so [embedded](/questions/tagged/embedded) -> [embedded-systems](/questions/tagged/embedded-systems), then do a batch retag.

Comment: Note that this would change >1,500 questions to use a tag found on just 39 questions.  I like the idea, which is why I suggested it, but I think it might be good to just merge without creating a synonym so the `<embed>` guys can have the tag they want so bad.

Comment: I think the only real problem doing a synonym in that direction would do is mess up those who might be following the big tag.  I would hope they could create a script to transfer people over, but I haven't heard of one yet.

Comment: I just ran a test on my meta site.  I created a [tags-merge-test] tag, followed it, and then merged it into [tags] without creating a synonym.  This changed my tag favorites from only [tags-merge-test] to only [tags].  We don't have to worry about transferring people over.

Comment: OTOH, maybe [tag:embedded] should become a derelict tag.  The `<embed>` guys can have the [tag:embed] tag and the embedded systems guys can have the [tag:embedded-systems] tag.